# SceneKit: Math question about positioning the camera node

Tags: 3d, scenekit

I am working on a Galaxy explorer using SceneKit.  I have a math question that I can't figure out.

[image]

In the above image, the cameraNode is hovering over the object NGC 5824 looking straight down into the plane of the image.  I need to calculate a new position for the cameraNode in order to be looking straight down at the object pointed to by the red arrow.

Basically the cameraNode has a current position and rotation.  I don't want the rotation to change but I want to change the position so the camera is over the new object.

The problem is trivial if the camera is looking directly down the z-axis.  I just set the x,y position of the cameraNode to the x,y position of new target node.  However, if the camera has an existing z rotation (as in the image), then the solution is more complex.

This must be a semi-simple transformation, but I can't wrap my head around it.  Can anyone provide the necessary hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.  Basically you need to figure out the translation between the new object and the old object (the deltaX, deltaY and deltaZ).  Then apply this translation to the point of view.  This positions the point of view in the same relative location above the new object as it was above the old object.